# If $(d,a)=1$ and $d|ab$ then $d|b$ .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Okay, checking to see if i'm on the right track.  I essentially did the same prove for Euclid's lemma but exchanged the $d$ for the $p$.  Is that the right idea?  Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: How about tagging (number-theory)?

Comment: I added the tag to Number Theory

Answer (score 1):

The condition $(d,a)=1$ is part of the hypothesis.  So the first two sentences of the proof are superfluous, and should be deleted.

Once that is done, the proof is good. The "By Bezout" part is too informal. You should say that by Bezout, there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $\dots$.

The proof  is, as you observed, essentially the same as the proof of Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: damn really? feels like really short leaving the first tow sentences of the proof out.  So just put: By Bezout
1=sa+td
b=sab+tdb
so d|b since it divides both terms on the right.∎

Comment: The first two sentences conclude that $(d,a)=1$. This looks very strange, since the theorem starts with "If $(d,a)=1". You were a bit too brief in the By Bezout sentence.

Comment: And yes, the proof is indeed  very short.  Of course, it uses a result (the "Bezout Identity") whose proof is less short.

Comment: The Proof for Euclid's Lemma the professor did in class was simply: Suppose p∤a, or we are done.  Then (p,a)<p and (p,a)|p, so (p,a)=1 by definition of prime.  By Bezout
1=sa+tp
b=sab+tpb
so p|b since it divides both terms on the right.∎

Comment: The proof of the Euclid Lemma in the prime $p$ case needs a little **more** than for your current result, for we need to show, from $p$ does not divide $a$, that $(a,p)=1$. Easy, but requires a sentence. But since in the current problem  we are **given** that $(d,a)=1$, that part of the proof of Euclid's Lemma is a) unnecessary and b) if you put it in, it will look as if you don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be a better way to word the proof?

Proof
Suppose d is prime and d∤a, we have (d,a)=1 and so
sd+ta=1.
Multiplying both sides by b, we obtain
sdb+tab=b.              (2)
Since d|ab and d|sdb, it follows that d|(sdb+tab).  This and (2) give d|b.∎

Or? Since Euclid's Lemma proves the (d,a)=1 Then I can say:
Proof
By Euclid's Lemma (d,a)=1 and so
sd+ta=1.
Multiplying both sides by b, we obtain
sdb+tab=b.              (2)
Since d|ab and d|sdb, it follows that d|(sdb+tab).  This and (2) give d|b.∎